# C# - how to kill excel process running in the background programmatically

Tags: c#, excel

I have a created a program to auto fill a invoice excel file so that it can be later printed. I am able to fill the cells and format them. But the excel process is still running in the background.

```
public void Write(tbl_Sale sale,List<SalesModel> saleCollection)
{  
    Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Wait);
    Excel.Application application = null;
    Workbook workbook = null;
    Worksheet inputSheet = null;
    Range range = null;

    try
    {
        if (sale != null)
        {
            if (saleCollection.Count != 0)
            {
                application = new Excel.Application();
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("Sample.xlsx");
                var sheet = "Invoice";
                workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(fileInfo.FullName);
                inputSheet = workbook.Worksheets.Cast<Worksheet>().Where(w => w.Name == sheet).FirstOrDefault(); 

                range = inputSheet.Cells;
                range.SetValue("G4", sale.Sale_ID);
                range.SetValue("G5", sale.Sale_Date);

                Range row = inputSheet.get_Range("A22", Missing.Value).EntireRow;

                for (int i = 0; i < saleCollection.Count; i++)
                {
                    row.Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, row);
                    range = inputSheet.Cells;
                    range.SetValue("A" + (22 + i), i + 1);

                    range = inputSheet.Cells;
                    range.SetValue("B" + (22 + i), saleCollection[i].Product.Prod_Code);
                    range = inputSheet.Range["B" + (22 + i) + ":" + "D" + (22 + i)];
                    range.Merge();

                    range = inputSheet.Cells;
                    range.SetValue("E" + (22 + i), saleCollection[i].Product.Prod_Name);
                    range = inputSheet.Range["E" + (22 + i) + ":" + "K" + (22 + i)];
                    range.Merge();
                    range.HorizontalAlignment = 1;

                    range = inputSheet.Cells;
                    range.SetValue("X" + (22 + i), saleCollection[i].SalesDetail.SaleD_Quantity);
                    range = inputSheet.Range["X" + (22 + i) + ":" + "Y" + (22 + i)];                          
                    range.Merge();
                    range.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    range.NumberFormat = "0.00";

                    range = inputSheet.Cells;
                    range.SetValue("Z" + (22 + i), saleCollection[i].SalesDetail.SaleD_Rate);
                    range = inputSheet.Range["Z" + (22 + i) + ":" + "AA" + (22 + i)];
                    range.Merge();
                    range.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    range.NumberFormat = "0.00";

                    range = inputSheet.Cells;
                    range.SetValue("AB" + (22 + i), saleCollection[i].SalesDetail.SaleD_Amount);
                    range = inputSheet.Range["AB" + (22 + i) + ":" + "AD" + (22 + i)];
                    range.Merge();
                    range.HorizontalAlignment = 1; ;
                    range.NumberFormat = "0.00";
                }
                range = inputSheet.Cells;
                range.SetValue("X" + (22 + saleCollection.Count + 2), saleCollection.Sum(s => s.SalesDetail.SaleD_Quantity));
                range.SetValue("AB" + (22 + saleCollection.Count + 2), sale.Sale_Total);
                fileInfo = new FileInfo("Invoices\\" + sale.Sale_ID + ".xlsx");

                workbook.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
                workbook.SaveAs(fileInfo.FullName, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges ,Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                releaseObject(row);
                MessageBox.Show("Invoice exported successfully", "Invoice Export", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);                      
               // Process.Start(fileInfo.FullName);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error while generating Excel report");
    }
    finally
    {
        workbook.Close(0);
        application.Quit();
        releaseObject(application);
        releaseObject(workbook);
        releaseObject(inputSheet);
        releaseObject(range);
        GC.Collect();
        Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Arrow);
    }
}
```

I am not able to kill the excel process from the background.I m not sure what I am doing wrong.The code above is the whole stuff I am doing for automating excel. Kindly please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is use an Initializer and a Deinitializer for the Excel objects, like so:

```
private void InitializeExcelObjects()
{
    _xlApp = new Excel.Application
    {
        SheetsInNewWorkbook = 2,
        StandardFont = "Tahoma",
        StandardFontSize = 11
    };

    _xlBook = _xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
    _xlApp.Windows.Application.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = false;

    _xlSheets = _xlBook.Worksheets;
    _xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)_xlSheets.Item[1];
    _xlSheetDelPerf = (Excel.Worksheet)_xlSheets.Item[2];
}

private void DeinitializeExcelObjects()
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_xlSheet);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_xlSheetDelPerf);

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_xlSheets);

    _xlBook.Close(false, null, null); 
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_xlBook);

    _xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
    _xlApp.Quit();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_xlApp);
    _xlApp = null;
}
```

They are called like this:

```
public void GenerateDuckbilledPlatypusRpt()
{
    try
    {
        InitializeExcelObjects();
        . . . // all the Excel generation code goes here
    }
    finally
    {
        DeinitializeExcelObjects();
    }
}
```

IOW, I think you could change your code to something like this:

```
public void Write(tbl_Sale sale,List<SalesModel> saleCollection)
{  
    Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Wait);
    Excel.Application application = null;
    Workbook workbook = null;
    Worksheet inputSheet = null;
    Range range = null;

    try
    {
        . . .
        InitializeExcelObjects();
        . . .
    }
    finally
    {
       DeinitializeExcelObjects();
       Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Arrow);
    }
}

private void InitializeExcelObjects()
{    
    application = new Excel.Application();

    workbook = application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

    sheets = workbook.Worksheets;
    inputSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets.Item[1];
}

private void DeinitializeExcelObjects()
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(inputSheet);

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheets);

    workbook.Close(false, null, null); 
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);

    application.DisplayAlerts = false;
    application.Quit();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
    application = null;
}
```

It works for me; YMMV

Comment: You're welcome; glad it helped. I'm trying to "pay it forward" for all the help I've gotten here where I can.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer:
[How do I properly clean up Excel interop objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects)

You are using `releaseObject(application)`, but that seems to refer to some method you have that is not shown.  Not sure what code is doing there.

Try using `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application)` in addition to heeding the cautions in the linked question.

Comment: That is basically the difference between my code and the OP's, I think (I'm using Marshal.ReleaseComObject() instead of releaseObject().